# Detect custom image marker in real time using OpenCV on iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, augmented-reality, marker

I would like some hints, maybe more, on detecting a custom image marker in a real-time video feed. I'm using OpenCV, iPhone and the camera feed.
By custom image marker I'm referring to a predefined image, but it can be any kind of image (not a specific designed marker). For example, it can be a picture of some skyscrapers.

I've already worked with ARTags and understand how they are detected, but how would I detect this custom image and especially find out its position & orientation?

What makes a good custom image to be detected successfully?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer is valid no more since Vuforia is now a paid engine.**

I think you should give Vuforia a try. It's a AR engine that can use any image you want as a marker. What makes a good marker for Vuforia is high frequency images.

http://www.qualcomm.com/solutions/augmented-reality

<s>Vuforia is a free to use engine.</s>

Comment: Vuforia looks very good. I've tested one of their samples and works like a charm. It also comes with a bonus: android support.

Comment: Vuforia is no longer free to use. You can test all functionalites during development, but you need to buy a commercial license to publish app.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular markers used in AR are

- AR markers (a simple form of QR codes) - those detected by AR tookit & others
- QR codes. There are plenty of examples on how to create/detect/read QR.
- Dot grids. Similar with the chess grids used in calibration. It seems their detection can be more robust than the classical chess grid. OpenCV has codes related to dot grid detection in the calibration part. Also, the OpenCV codebase offers a good starting point to extract 3D position and orientation.
- Chess grids. Similar to dot grids. They were the standard calibration pattern, and some people used them for marker detection of a long time. But they lost their position to dot grids recently, when some people discovered that dots can be detected with better accuracy.

**Note**:

Grids are symmetrical. I bet you already know that. But that means you will not be able to 
recover full orientation data from them. You will get the plane where the grid lies, but nothing more.

**Final note**:

Code and examples for the first two are easily found on the Internet. They are considered the best by many people. If you decide to use the grid patterns, you have to enjoy some math and image processing work :) And it will take more.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking to use a custom/any image (not a specifically designed marker). I've looked more on the internet, and some call it  markerless tracking.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, QR codes are not that good (or not good at all) for detecting the orientation. But... I might be wrong

Comment: There are two ways to track something: either you have the choice of the tracking image - and you select an AR code, because it's fast and reliable, either you cannot, so you track whatever image you have to: a flower, a book, etc. In this case, the feature descriptors are used: SIFT/SURF/ORB/FREAK to train your tracker with any image. They will perform well if the image has enough distinctive features: A textured object, like a magazine, a panorama, etc. See here an example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FirtmYcC0Vc.

Comment: @AndreiStanescu It's not markerless tracking since you are looking for markers. It may be a custom image, but it is still a marker (engines like "Vuforia" use images for tracking). Markerless tracking is that performed by algorithms like PTAM, and it's quite a different thing.